# select element which have not id

Tags: css

```
<div id="example">
    <input id="one"> //type may be anything
    <input>
    <input id="two">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Now how could I select `#example's` all elements which has not id?

Comment: css-solution required

Comment: `#example :not(#foo)` etc. Note: your HTML **isn't valid**. Note#2 : **ID** must be **unique**.

Comment: @downvoter please comment!

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Showing an example should be code that is of the highest standard you are capable of. Please show some respect towards people who are helping you and put effort into writing your question. I guess the downvotes just reflected the quality of your question before my edit (and your research effort into CSS selectors, possibly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to `select #example's all elements which has not id`, you could use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) pesudo-class as follows:

```css
#example :not([id]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsbin.com/mibiboki/1/edit)**.

Comment: It would be better to use a specific selector, not such a generic one.

Comment: +1 Does not work in IE8 and lower, but CSS2 selectors are not enough to do what the OP needs.

Comment: @kapa That's right, in this case, the OP can use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) for IE 6-8